Quick question about MGFs; Is $M_X(t)$ always strictly positive?
I recently had an assignment where I had to prove that, if $X,Y,Z$ are all independent random variables and $X+Z$ has the same distribution as $Y+Z$ then $X$ has the same distribution as $Y$. These were all $L^\infty$ random variables, so I used MGFs to prove it. I showed that $$M_X(t)M_Z(t)=M_Y(t)M_Z(t),$$ and cancelled the $M_Z(t)$ on both sides to arrive at the desired conclusion.
The only place I lost some points was at this step where I cancelled, and my professor took off some points and left a note saying "divides by $M_Z(t)$ but does not show that it's non-zero". This almost didn't even seem worth saying because it seems so obvious to me, and he's out of town for the week, so I can't ask him directly. So I just want to be sure that I'm not crazy about MGFs always being positive; since $f(y)=e^y$ is always positive, $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX}) > \mathbb{E}(0)=0.$
Am I missing something?
Thanks.

$\mathbb{E}(e^{tX}) > \mathbb{E}(0)=0$ convinces me, at least for those $t$ where $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})$ exists.  But stating "... since $M_Z(t)>0$" might be desirable when you perform your division/cancellation.

As $e^{tx}$ is a convex function for any $t\in \mathbb R$, by Jensen inequality not only for RVs with bounded support but also for any random variable with finite mgf over a neighbourhood of zero (minimal condition) we have for all $t\in \mathbb R$:
$$M_X(t)=\mathbb E(e^{tX}) \ge e^{t\mathbb E(X)}>0.$$
Recall that if the mgf is finite over a neighbourhood of zero, then $\mathbb E(X^k)$ is also finite for any integer $k$.

I agree with you that the MGF of $X,\,Y$ and $Z$ are strictly positive is obvious. I think your professor was looking for the following:
By $L^\infty$ assumption, there is $M>0$ so that $\max\{|X|,|Y|,|Z|\} \le M$ almost surely. So
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{t X} \right] \ge\mathbb{E}\left[e^{t\cdot \text{essinf}\{X\}} \right] \ge\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-t M} \right] = e^{-t M} > 0,
$$
where $\text{essinf}\{X\}$ is the essential inf of $X$. Similar argument for finite upper bound.
There are of course random variables whose moment generating function does not exists or is identically zero. Simplest one is that, if $X$ is identically negative infinity with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and zero else (people might disagree on whether this is defined).
